# How to use Foundicon inside Zurb Foundations button

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I want to use foundicon inside foundations button like this.
(I'm using button `small radius` and `foundicon-refresh`.)

But as a default the icon is aligned 1 pixel above than a text.
If I set `vertical-align: top` for `.button`, then icon and text are go along with good, but I want set it middle of button.

So I want to drag down 1 pixel icon and text like third picture below.
To to this I must change `.button.small { padding-top: 0.625em; padding-bottom: 0.5625em; }` to `.button.small { padding-top: 0.725em; padding-bottom: 0.4625em; }`.

In scss file for foundations padding size are defined by calculation. Even if I write the values `foundation_and_overrides.scss`, that is overrided by default setting. (It seems, Override are only allowed by variables.)

How can I override default value? I don't want to use `!important` if possible.

Or is there better way to do this?

[image]

```
<a href="#" class="button small radius"><i class='general foundicon-refresh'></i> Reload</a>
```

Comment: have you tried vertical-align: middle;

Comment: yes, I tried `middle` and `bottom` for icon and `middle` and `top` for text. Only `top` for text had an effect.